# Exportacion jar ejecutable

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Estoy creando un proyecto que cuenta con una base de datos (en Access 2016), el problema es que no se como exportar la base de datos con el jar ejecutable, en caso de poder hacerse, ¿debería cambiar la ruta de la base en el código?
Esta es mi clase`

```
package Swing.pruebas.SqlFiles;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConnectDB {
private Connection con;
private Statement smt;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private final String controlador;
private final String nombre_db;
private final String usuario;
private final String contraseña;

public ConnectDB(){
    this.controlador = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    this.nombre_db = "C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Desktop\\eclipse_java\\TutorialesBlog\\src\\Swing\\pruebas\\Usuarios.accdb";
    this.usuario = "";
    this.contraseña = "";
}

public boolean establecerConexion() throws SQLException{
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+this.nombre_db, this.usuario, this.contraseña);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al realizar la conexión: "+e);
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }

    try{
        this.smt = this.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al realizar la conexión: "+e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public ResultSet ejecutarSentencia(String sql) throws SQLException{
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = this.smt.executeQuery(sql);
    return rs;
}

public int ejecutarSentenciaUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException{
    int rs;
    rs = this.smt.executeUpdate(sql);
    return rs;
}
}
```

Que ruta debo asignarle a la variable nombre_db para que el programa pueda usar la DB, en cualquier ordenador. ¿Tendré que poner la DB en el JAR ejecutable exportado? El código actual sí funciona.

Comment: Intenta explicarte un poco mejor, comenta que has intentado y pon el código.

Comment: Ese es el código

Answer (score 4):

A ver, suponiendo que esa base de datos Access es únicamente de tu aplicación y nadie más la usa, lo suyo es empaquetarla dentro del JAR en el que vayas a distribuir tu aplicación, como bien apuntas al plantear el problema (por ejemplo, podrías tener una subcarpeta llamada "resources", copiarla ahí y que esta subcarpeta se incluya en el JAR).

A partir de ahí, ese nombre_db se calcula de la siguiente forma:

```
URL url = Solution.class.getResource("resources/Usuarios.accdb");
nombre_db = url.getPath();
```

Para crear el jar con esa carpeta es tan sencillo como

```
jar -cvf nombre_del_jar.jar bin/
```

suponiendo que los .class los tienes en la carpeta bin y que la carpeta resources también se copia ahí dentro. Si no es así, sólo tendrías que adaptar tu código para incluir o no el nombre de la carpeta y añadir la misma al final del comando jar para que incluya su contenido.

Espero haberte servido de ayuda.

Comment: me parece excelente tu respuesta, empaquetarla y crear una subcarpeta es la mejor idea!

Comment: Esta respuesta funciona bien, pero por favor ten en cuenta que de esta forma NO vas a poder actualizar la BD. Solo te servirá para leerla.

Comment: Correcto, y no me había fijado en que tiene un método para ejecutar updates. Por tanto, lo suyo sería, en el main, copiar el fichero a alguna ruta del sistema de archivos del usuario y trabajar contra esa copia.

Comment: Mediante eso, en que ruta deberia poner la carpeta res

Comment: Mediante eso, en que ruta deberia poner la carpeta res,mi proyecto esta en C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\eclipse_java\MiProyecto\bin\com\bruno\ y aqui estan todas mis clases

Comment: Como por la ruta que estás usando utilizas Eclipse, lo más fácil es crear la carpeta _res_ bajo la raíz del proyecto _MiProyecto_, añadirla al build path (botón derecho la carpeta -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder, con lo que te funcionará cuando lo pruebes bajo Eclipse) y luego, exportar el proyecto mediante Export -> Java -> Jar File y asegurarte que se incluye la carpeta _res_.